# Monitoring the status of the last execution of a pipeline in Datadog CI Visibility

Tags: github-actions, alert, monitoring, datadog

We use Datadog for most of our monitoring and we are starting to use GitHub Actions Workflows more. There's a particular Workflow we use for continuous deployment and so we'd like to be alerted if it starts failing.

I've set up CI Pipeline Visibility integration, which means I can make CI Pipeline Monitors. But I can't figure out how when crafting a pipeline I can ask a question about "the status of the *last* execution on a given pipeline". (This pipeline uses the GH Actions "concurrency" feature so they do run in sequence.) I don't want to query the status "every execution that happened in the last 15 minutes" — I want to query "precisely the status of the last execution, which might have been a minute ago and might have been an hour ago". Is this possible with the CI Pipeline Monitor feature?

(What I *actually* want is a monitor that says "alert if at all times over the last N minutes, the status of the last execution has been failed". So I don't want to alert immediately on failure, but if a failure is followed quickly by a success that doesn't need to alert either. I think I can see how to ask the question "have there been any failures in the last N minutes" or "have there been any successes in the last N minutes" but not in a way that completely forgets what's happening when N minutes passes? And not in a way that understands that a success after a failure means we should resolve, but not the other way around.)